# How to add VB.Net event drop-down navigation bar to C# in Visual Studio '15?

Tags: c#, vb.net, ide

In VB.Net you can select an object in the text editor, then on the last drop down list on top of the editor, you can select an event from said object and auto-generate the event method. Can this same navigation bar be enabled for C# in Visual Studio 2015?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it can. That toolbar uses the `WithEvents` pattern to add event handlers and this pattern is not available in c#

C# makes it easy to add the handlers automatically though when you type

```
 myobj.MyEvent +=
```

Then just hit tab to automatically add a handler.

Comment: The c# IDE does automatically create the method and hook up handlers when you select an event from the Properties viewer (switch View from properties to events)